# Assign multiple selections from Tkinter listbox to a callable variable & "Application not response" when quit Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am a very newbie on TK, just combined several solutions together to get what I want. My codes:

```
from Tkinter import *
window = Tk() 
window.title('Targeted foods_Multiple selection') 

def CurSeletion(event):
    values = [mylistbox.get(i) for i in mylistbox.curselection()]
    print('; '.join(values))    

# for scrolling vertically 
yscrollbar = Scrollbar(window) 
yscrollbar.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y) 
  
label = Label(window, 
              text = "Select the food items below :  ",
              padx = 10, pady = 10) 
label.pack() 
mylistbox = Listbox(window, selectmode = "multiple",  
               yscrollcommand = yscrollbar.set) 
  
# Widget expands horizontally and vertically by assigning both to fill option 
mylistbox.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10, 
          expand = YES, fill = "both") 
  

 x =['malabar spinach',
 'new zealand spinach',
 'spinach',
 'spinach mustard',
 'tomato',
 'tomato, cherry',
 'tomato, paste',
 'water spinach',
 'water spinach, green',
 'water spinach, white']
    
    mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', CurSeletion)
    
    # coloring alternative lines of listbox  
    for each_item in range(len(x)):   
        mylistbox.insert(END,x[each_item]) 
        mylistbox.itemconfig(each_item, bg = "white") 
    
# Attach listbox to vertical scrollbar  
yscrollbar.config(command = mylistbox.yview) 

#Quit
Button(window, text="Quit", command=window.destroy).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

I got several problems:

1. It is a multiple selections, it outputted several lines every time when I made new clicks, like:

"spinach

spinach; tomato, cherry

spinach; tomato, cherry; water spinach, green

spinach; tomato, cherry; water spinach, green; water spinach, white".

How can I just output the last line what I want.

2. I want to quit Tkinter, but when I clicked "Quit" button, my popup window dead, showed "Application Not responding", and alway let my Jupyter Notebook kernel dead. How can I fix it?
3. How can I assign my selections into a list that I can use outside?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem of item 1? It is what your code does.  For item 3, you already save the selection in a list: `values`.  If you want to access it elsewhere, add `global values` inside `CurSeletion()`

Comment: Thanks. It doesn’t matter, but for question 1, how can I delete the previous selections and only show the final selection? For question 3, your suggestion works. Thanks so much.

Comment: Then remove `selectmode` option.

Comment: But I do want multiple selections. Never mind, now will not affect my  `values` . I am just picky. Thanks a lot. Could you please advise me the "Not responding" problem? I always have to restart the kernel if I force quit the app window. And how can I change my previous elections and get a new `values` ? If I run the Tkinter cell again, it will collapse too.

Comment: Did you get the same "Not responding" problem when running in a console/terminal?  If not, the issue is related to Jupyter (I don't use it, so I can't tell what is wrong).  I don't get what you want *"only show the final selection"* but *"want multiple selections"*.

Comment: Sorry, per se my comment above, I delete the `#Quit` code, all good now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer above comments from @acw1668